# How to save data in a dataframe?

Tags: r

Sorry, really beginner question: I want to generate a data frame with random data. I want my data frame to be 10 rows by 20 columns, where each row contains data from a random sample generated by rnorm. How do I do this?

Comment: Please share any code you have tried and be clear about this part you are stuck on.

Comment: `example(data.frame)`

Answer (score 1):

Producing a matrix may be easier, but this can be converted to a dataframe:

```
rownum <- 10
colnum <- 20
yourdf <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(rownum * colnum), nrow=rownum))
```